Flutter list modification from daily (with sublist) to monthly with sum of (sublist)
I have list like this
[
  {
      "date":"2024/01/01",
      "total":20
      "detail":[
         {
            "person":"amir",
            "income":5
         },
         {
            "person":"james",
            "income":10
         },
         {
            "person":"kevin",
            "income":3
         }
      ]
   },
  {
      "date":"2024/01/02",
      "total":30
      "detail":[
         {
            "person":"thomas",
            "income":5
         },
         {
            "person":"james",
            "income":11
         },
         {
            "person":"kevin",
            "income":10
         }
      ]
   },
  {
      "date":"2024/02/01",
      "total":20
      "detail":[
         {
            "person":"amir",
            "income":5
         },
         {
            "person":"james",
            "income":10
         },
         {
            "person":"kevin",
            "income":3
         }
      ]
   },
  {
      "date":"2024/02/03",
      "total":20
      "detail":[
         {
            "person":"amir",
            "income":5
         },
         {
            "person":"james",
            "income":10
         },
         {
            "person":"kevin",
            "income":3
         }
      ]
   },
  {
      "date":"2024/02/04",
      "total":20
      "detail":[
         {
            "person":"rodrigo",
            "income":5
         },
         {
            "person":"james",
            "income":10
         },
         {
            "person":"kevin",
            "income":3
         }
      ]
   },
  {
      "date":"2024/03/03",
      "total":20
      "detail":[
         {
            "person":"amir",
            "income":5
         },
         {
            "person":"james",
            "income":10
         },
         {
            "person":"frans",
            "income":3
         }
      ]
   },

]

Which the original class is
class StaffIncome {
  const StaffIncome({required this.person, required this.income});
  final String person;
  final double income;


}
 class DailySummary {
 const DailySummary({
    required this.date,
    required this.total,
    this.incomeList = const <StaffIncome>[],
  });


  final DateTime date;
  final double total;
  final List<StaffIncome> incomeList;

}

I want to group it so it will based on month, and it sum for (total ), and for the income of each staff will be summed
so that list will be generated like this
[ 
  {
       "month":"01",
       "year":"2024",
       "total":50,
       "detail":[
           {
              "person":"amir",
              "monthlyIncome":5 
           },      
           {
              "person":"james",
              "monthlyIncome":21 
           },      
           {
              "person":"kevin",
              "monthlyIncome":13 
           },      
           {
              "person":"thomas",
              "monthlyIncome":5 
           },      
                ] 
  },
  {
       "month":"02",
       "year":"2024",
       "total":60,
       "detail":[
           {
              "person":"amir",
              "monthlyIncome":10 
           },      
           {
              "person":"james",
              "monthlyIncome":30 
           },      
           {
              "person":"kevin",
              "monthlyIncome":9 
           },      
           {
              "person":"rodrigo",
              "monthlyIncome":5 
           },      
                ] 
  },
  {
       "month":"03",
       "year":"2024",
       "total":20,
       "detail":[
           {
              "person":"amir",
              "monthlyIncome":5 
           },      
           {
              "person":"james",
              "monthlyIncome":10 
           },      
           {
              "person":"frans",
              "monthlyIncome":3 
           },      
                ], 
  },
]

I have successfull with the use of fluter collection to group by month and year for the total
class MonthYearFilterModel extends Equatable {
  const MonthYearFilterModel({required this.year, required this.month});

  final int year;
  final int month;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        year,
        month,
      ];
}

class MonthlyTotal extends Equatable {
  const MonthlyTotal({
    required this.monthYear,
    required this.total,
  });
  final MonthYearFilterModel monthYear;
  final double total;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        monthYear,
        total,
      ];
}

and the code is like this
Map<MonthYearFilterModel, double> _groupByMonthAndSumTotal(
  List<DailySummary> list,
  MonthYearFilterModel Function(DailySummary) groupByGetter,
  double Function(List<double>) applyFunction,
) {
  final tmpMap =
      groupBy<DailySummary, MonthYearFilterModel>(list, groupByGetter);

  return tmpMap.map((key, value) {
    return MapEntry(
      key,
      applyFunction(
        value.map((e) {
          return e.total;
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  });
}

List<MonthlyTotal> monthlySalesList({
  required List<DailySummary> listDailySummary,
}) {
  double sumDouble(List<double> list) => list.fold(
        0,
        (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element,
      );

  final mapRes = _groupByMonthAndSumTotal(
    listDailySummary,
    (e) {
      return MonthYearFilterModel(
        month: e.date.month,
        year: e.date.year,
      );
    },
    sumDouble,
  );

  final res = <MonthlyTotal>[];
  mapRes.forEach((k, v) {
    res.add(
      MonthlyTotal(
        monthYear: k,
        total: v,
      ),
    );
  });

  return res;
}

BUT STILL NOT ABLE TO GROUP The "detail" PART
Note : ie, there are 6 person (amir, james, kevin, thomas, rodrigo, frans ), it may be more people
Thank you for your answer / contribution / help

any particular reason to use groupBy?

i did put groupby on the topic, because i think we may need something like that to sum (income) groupby person

I have tried some solution with the group by but seems unable to solve
so loop through and putIfAbsent method able become the solution that i am looking for
  class PersonIncome {
  PersonIncome({
    required this.person,
    this.income = 0,
  });

  final String person;
  double income;
}
   

class MonthlySummary {
  MonthlySummary({
    required this.monthYear,
    this.total = 0,
  });

  final MonthYearFilterModel monthYear;
  double total;
  Map<Person, PersonIncome> personIncome = {};
}

List<MonthlySummary> summaryByMonth({
  required List<DailySummary> listDailySummary,
}) {

  final monthlyTotalSummary = <MonthYearFilterModel, MonthlySummary>{};

  for (final item in listDailySummary) {
    final monthYear =
        MonthYearFilterModel(year: item.date.year, month: item.date.month);

    final monthSummary = monthlyTotalSummary.putIfAbsent(monthYear, () {
      return MonthlySummary(
        monthYear: monthYear,
        outlet: outlet,
      );
    });

    monthSummary.total =
          monthSummary.total + item.total;

    //STAFF INCOME LIST

    PersonIncome incomeDetail;
    for (final detail in item.incomeList) {

      incomeDetail = monthSummary.personIncome.putIfAbsent(
        detail.person,
        () {
          return personIncome(
            person: detail.person,
          );
        },
      );

      incomeDetail.income = incomeDetail.income + detail.income;

    }

  }

  final result = <MonthlySummary>[];
  for (final item in monthlyTotalSummary.values) {
    result.add(item);
  }

  return result;
}

Original idea by pskink
https://pastebin.com/UF5hiHwZ
Thank you pskink
